# Splunk left jion is not giving as exepcted

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Requirement: I want to find out, payment card information used in a particular day are there any tele sales order placed with the same payment card information.

I tried with below query it is supposed to give me all the payment card information from online orders and matching payment info from telesales.   But i am not giving  correct results basically results shows there are no telesales for payment information, but when i search splunk i am finding telesales as well.  So the query wrong.

```
index="orders" "Online order received" earliest=-9d latest=-8d 
    | rex field=message "paymentHashed=(?<payHash>.([a-z0-9_\.-]+))" 
    | rename timestamp as  onlineOrderTime 
    | table payHash, onlineOrderTime 
    | join type=left payHash [search index="orders"  "Telesale order received" earliest=-20d latest=-5m | rex field=message "paymentHashed=(?<payHash>.([a-z0-9_\.-]+))" | rename timestamp as TeleSaleTime | table payHash, TeleSaleTime] 
    | table payHash, onlineOrderTime, TeleSaleTime
```

Please help me in fixing the query or a query to find out results for my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *do* want to do this with a `join`, what you had, slightly changed, *should* be correct:

```
index="orders" "Online order received" earliest=-9d latest=-8d 
| rex field=message "paymentHashed=(?<payHash>.([a-z0-9_\.-]+))" 
| stats values(_time) as onlineOrderTime by payHash
| join type=left payHash 
    [search index="orders" "Telesale order received" earliest=-20d latest=-5m
    | rex field=message "paymentHashed=(?<payHash>.([a-z0-9_\.-]+))" 
    | rename timestamp as TeleSaleTime 
    | stats values(TeleSaleTime) by payHash ]
| rename timestamp as onlineOrderTime
```

Note the added `| stats values(...) by` in the subsearch: you need to ensure you've removed any duplicates from the list, which this will do. By using `values()`, you'll also ensure if there're repeated entries for the `payHash` field, they get grouped together. (Similarly, added a `| stats values...` *before* the subsearch to speed the whole operation.)

---

You should be able to do this without a `join`, too:

```
index="orders" (("Online order received" earliest=-9d latest=-8d) OR "Telesale order received" earliest=-20d)) 
| rex field=_raw "(?<order_type>\w+) order received"
| rex field=message "paymentHashed=(?<payHash>.([a-z0-9_\.-]+))"
| stats values(order_type) as order_type values(_time) as orderTimes by payHash
| where mvcount(order_type)>1
```

After you've ensured your times are correct, you can format them - here's one I use frequently:

```
| eval onlineOrderTime=strftime(onlineOrderTime,"%c"), TeleSaleTime=strftime(TeleSaleTime,"%c")
```

You may also need to do further reformatting, but these should get you close

---

fwiw - I'd wonder why you were trying to look at Online orders from only 9 days ago, but Telesale orders from 20 days ago to now: but that's just me.

Answer (score -1):

The `join` command expects a list of field names on which events from each search will be matched.  If no fields are listed then all fields are used.  In the example, the fields 'onlineOrderTime' and 'TeleSaleTime' exist only on one side of the join so no matches can be made.  The fix is simple: specify the common field name.  `... | join type=left payHash ...`.

Comment: i tried it already, now i updated the actual question as well. no luck

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you can delete the last row `| table payHash, onlineOrderTime, TeleSaleTime` beacuse it doesn't do anything(the join command already joins both tables you created).

Secondly, when running both queries separately -  both queries have the same "payHash"es? both queries return back a table with the true results?

Because by the looks of it, you used the join command correctly...